# Visualizing live AMR audio on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, amr

I have code to record audio working well.  I would like to add some visualization of the audio while the recording is happening, something like a waveform, or just a plain thermometer style visualization, so the user knows something is being recorded.  I haven't found any listener or method I can query to get something like the current volume of the recorded audio.  My thought right now is that I can parse the AMR bytestream and try to visualize it directly, but the complexity there is prohibitive for this feature, so I was hoping there is a more straightforward API to use.  Alternatively, if you know about Java-ME amr parsing code, that could be useful as well - I admit I haven't done much research on the AMR side yet, as I was hoping there was a more direct way of measuring the current audio volume level.

```
_player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(
        "capture://audio?encoding=amr");
_player.realize();
_rcontrol = (RecordControl)_player.getControl("RecordControl");
_rcontrol.setRecordStream(_audioBuf);
_rcontrol.setRecordSizeLimit(200 * 1024);
_rcontrol.startRecord();
_player.start();
```